# What has been the popularity trend for D&D Miniatures?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system, miniatures

How have D&D Miniatures been faring in terms of popularity? Has it been decreasing or increasing; slowly or fast? Recently (as in the last year), and if possible, on a broader scale as well. On the internet as a whole, as opposed to local trends.

Anything conclusive within a limited scope is a welcome answer (e.g. number of topics/tags on a given card game site). Also the answer could be solely based on personal experience and anecdotal evidence thought to be representing of a broader trend, such as popularity perceived from internet forums.

Comment: @whoever, when you vote a question down, it's quite helpful to leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: It would indeed. D&D Miniatures, despite the name, is both a card and a board game.

Comment: I downvoted, and I'm now adding a close-vote for "too broad". This question seems to be asking for an enormous statistical analysis, which is way out of scope for this site.

Comment: Definitely not enormous statistical analysis, I edited the question to reflect it. And if it's not on-topic on this site, as you suggest, it wouldn't be on any other as well. But I think it's an objective and answerable question, easy even for someone who has been in constant touch with D&D Miniatures recently, as is not my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last expansion for the game was *Lords of Madness* in 2010. The release of the *Dragon Collector's Set* this December -— a 5-figure fixed set -- suggests that the future of the line will be in the arena of figures to assist the play of the *Dungeons & Dragons* RPG. This evidence supports the idea that the "popularity trend" for this game is **declining, if not moribund**. However, [Wizards of the Coast has announced](http://critical-hits.com/2011/08/08/gen-con-2011-dd-new-products-seminar/) that, in 2012, a new miniatures-based skirmish game will rise to replace it.

Comment: Nice, this seems a great summary of the situation, thanks!